# Taxonomy: Why 'with_front' => false DOES NOT WORK?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Seriously, why `'with_front' => false` does not work as it should be? It is supposed to remove TAXONOMY BASE NAME and my question is why it does not work?

I just dont want the taxonamy base slug appear in my URL and codex says `'with_front' =>` false should help but it does not. Leaving the slug empty like `'slug'=> ''` generates 404 error.

```
register_taxonomy("tax_categories", array("products"), array(
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => "Categories",
    "singular_label" => "Category",
    "show_ui" => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    "rewrite" => array(     
        'with_front' => false,      
        'hierarchical' => true      
        )
    ));
```

This issue supposed to be fixed http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16807

Please help to understand that. Thank you.

Comment: Try and Go to your settings-->permalinks and click save, or flush the rewrite rules.

Comment: As Manny said, `with_front` does *not* remove the taxonomy base name. I assume you want to convert the link format from `/tax-categories/banana/` to `/banana/`? There was a question about this (it's quite complicated), but I can't find it right now.

Comment: thats is exactly what is needed.

Comment: The problem is you sorta need the taxonomy name in there so that WordPress knows the next thing is the taxonomy term.  The only way I know to do it is if you create a completely custom permalink.  Do you know what you want your permalink to look like?

Comment: The other question @JanFabry refers to might be this one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/remove-taxonomy-base-or-term-from-url/21102#21102

Answer (score 11):

All with_front does is toggle whether or not a taxonomy link can have something else in front of it ie extra permalink stuff from the permalinks options page. For example with_front set to true makes this possible:

```
blah.com/2011/09/tax/term
```

with it set to false, all you can do is:

```
blah.com/tax/term
```

Comment: I see... does not help though. How to remove the /TAX/ part from taxonomy?

Answer (score 11):

To remove the taxonomy base name, you can use:

```
'rewrite' => ['slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false]
```

However, **this will make your (basic post type) posts go 404**, if you have permalinks set to `http://example.com/sample-post/`. It seems you cannot have both custom taxonomy and posts reside in the root. Therefore you would go to Permalinks settings and set **Custom structure** , e.g. `/blog/%postname%/`.

**One more note**

A side effect is that your CPTs would have this "front", too, e.g. `blog/products`. This is where `'with_front' => false` comes to play. It's designed to get you rid of the custom structure start. So in your product type registration, you would have:

```
register_post_type( 'products',  array(
           'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'products',
                'with_front' => false
            ),
            /* ... */
));
```

Comment: Someone flagged your answer. But I found it appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Use the code below:

```
'rewrite' => array( 
    'slug'          => '.',
    'with_front'    => false 
),
```

Notice that when you rewrite the slug that the default page template is opened, when you go to the taxonomy page.

Comment: In addition to what @tf said, also please explain *why* your code provides a solution.

Comment: This solution does work and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Give me a 404, despite me resaving the permalinks. It does rewrite the URL in the browser (but not within the post permalink area), but still gives 404 in browser.

Comment: Did not know this was possible for a taxonomy. I've used it with keeping the slug intact. Works good!