# Taxonomy URL Rewrite

Tags: taxonomy

I'm having some issues with custom taxonomy URLs and wonder if someone can assist.  As an example, I have:

```
mysite.com/taxonomy1/term1
mysite.com/taxonomy2/term2
mysite.com/taxonomy3/term3
```

The trouble with this is that anyone manually entering the URL needs to know which taxonomy the term belongs to. Is there a way to either remove the taxonomy reference?:

```
mysite.com/term1
mysite.com/term2
mysite.com/term3
```

or standardize the parent?:

```
mysite.com/standard-taxonomy/term1
mysite.com/standard-taxonomy/term2
mysite.com/standard-taxonomy/term3
```

Comment: Check this post, removing base slug will resolve your issue. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/remove-taxonomy-base-or-term-from-url Thanks Sanny

Comment: I found a great piece of code that does exactly what I was looking for at https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/remove-taxonomy-slug-from-urls.html